# Cocos2D touch-to-move-to-destination controls?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I have a spaceship. I want the spaceship to move to the area that the player has touched. So far I have this code:

```
- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  // initialize touch
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  // point out location of touch
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

  // move to location
  [player runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:location]];

  // log action
  CCLOG(@"player moved");

}
```

However, this has a quirk: When I touch in certain places the shuttle will move slow, up instead of down, and other weird movements. Is there any way to correct this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the line :

```
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
```

Add this line:

```
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
```

Then try. :)